# how to hide Navbar in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i want to hide the navbar in the render when there is a user logged in so when user is true i want to hide the whole navbar same with reverse if there is no user then navbar stays..basically when the user is loged in only the welcome page should be shown.but right now the navbar is also visible along with the welcome page which is wrong

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import fire from "./config/fire";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Home from "./components/home/home";
import Quiz from "./components/quiz/quiz";
import Login from "./components/quiz/login";
import { Button, Col, Nav, Navbar, ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import Signup from "./components/quiz/signup";
import Welcome from "./components/home/welcome";
import { FiLogIn } from "react-icons/fi";
import { TiHome } from "react-icons/ti";
//import login from ".login/components/quiz/login";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      viewquiz: false,
      viewHome: true,
      viewLogin: false,
      viewSignup: false,
      user: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
  }

  authListener() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          user,
          viewHome: false,
          viewLogin: false,
          viewSignup: false
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null, viewHome: true });
      }
    });
  }

  changetoQuiz = () => {
    this.setState({
      viewquiz: !this.state.viewquiz,
      viewHome: false,
      viewLogin: false,
      viewSignup: false
    });
  };

  changetoLogin = () => {
    this.setState({
      viewLogin: true,
      viewHome: false,
      viewSignup: false
    });
  };

  changetoSignup = () => {
    this.setState({
      viewSignup: true,
      viewHome: false,
      viewLogin: false
    });
  };
  changetoHome = () => {
    this.setState({
      viewHome: true
      //  viewLogin: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <body>
        <div className="App">
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar id="navbar" bg="dark" variant="dark">
              <ButtonToolbar>
                <Button bg="dark" variant="dark" onClick={this.changetoHome}>
                  <Link to="/">
                    Home <TiHome />
                  </Link>
                </Button>
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Button bg="dark" variant="dark" onClick={this.changetoLogin}>
                    <Link to="/Login">
                      Login <FiLogIn />
                    </Link>
                  </Button>

                  <Button
                    bg="dark"
                    variant="dark"
                    onClick={this.changetoSignup}
                  >
                    <Link to="/Signup">Signup</Link>
                  </Button>
                </Nav>
              </ButtonToolbar>
            </Navbar>
            {this.state.viewHome ? (
              <Route path="/Home" component={Home} exact />
            ) : null}
            {this.state.viewLogin ? (
              <Route path="/Login" component={Login} exact />
            ) : null}
            {this.state.viewSignup ? (
              <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} exact />
            ) : null}
          </BrowserRouter>
          {this.state.viewHome ? <Home /> : null}
          {this.state.user ? <Welcome /> : null}
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So, `{ this.state.user.authenticated ? null : <Navbar ....... }`? This seems pretty straight forward: don't _render_ the navbar if the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is authenticated built in function?

Comment: You tell me, this is your code, not mine. Somewhere you're storing the user's authentication flag. Check that flag during `render()`. Your authListener suggests you're storing it in `this.state.user`, what's actually _in_ that user object, only you know at the moment.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it checks if user has logged in already if it does it goes straight to the welcome page rather than loging in again

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans { this.state.user.authenticated ? null : <Navbar ....... } this works btw its correct thanks